# Nodejs - how to uninstall older version of nodejs and install new version of nodejs in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

my react project need updated nodejs.
so how i can reinstall my node js to latest version in Ubuntu 16.04.

*my current node version is*

```
node -v
v6.0.0
```

*my current npm version is*

```
npm -v
3.8.6
```

ideally i want to reinstall my nodejs, node & npm to its newest version.

Comment: https://snapcraft.io/node

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/27373/install-uninstall-nodejs-ubuntu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Uninstall NodeJS from Ubuntu**

The command will remove the package but retain the configuration files.

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To remove both the package and the configuration files run:

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

**Install NodeJS on Ubuntu**

Adding the NodeJS PPA to Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
```

After successfully adding the NodeJS PPA, It’s time now to install NodeJS using the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Verfiying the version of NodeJS and NPM

```
node -v
npm -v
```

More Info: http://www.rscoder.com/2020/04/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-nodejs.html

Comment: After uninstall, Restart system and then check node version, If showing there is some issue otherwise follow installation steps :)

Comment: You also need to run `sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh` after curl command before running install nodejs command.  This worked for me:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: The lastest is `https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x` by Oct. 2023. However, from the developer page: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions "The installation scripts setup_XX.x are no longer supported and are not needed anymore, as the installation process is straightforward for any RPM and DEB distro.
"

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall NodeJS from Ubuntu

- `sudo apt-get remove nodejs`
- `sudo apt-get update`

Follow below link to install latest nodeJs in ubuntu

https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nodejs-npm-on-ubuntu/

Ones you installed successfully, then if you want to check node version use below command.

`node -v`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 10.16.0
```

Or `n latest` to install latest version of node.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link to install and use other version of nodeJs in ubuntu

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59392965/9490901